# $L^\infty$ error estimate for optimal $L^2$ approximants

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation-theory, finite-element-method

I have a function $u\in H^m(\Omega)$ for which I find $u_h \in \mathbb{P}^p(\Omega)$, the best $p$ polynomial approximant in an $L^2$ sense

$$ u_h = \arg \inf_{v\in\mathbb{P}^p(\Omega)} \| u - u_h \|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$

Is there a way to estimate $\| u - u_h \|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$ in terms of the diameter of $\Omega$?

I'm thinking something along the lines of
$$
\exists s \in \mathbb{R} :\ 
\|u - u_h \|_{L^\infty} \lesssim h^{s} \| u - u_h \|_{L^2(\Omega)}$$

where $h$ is the diameter of $\Omega$.

Comment: You should add the 'approximation theory' tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is such a result given the right hypotheses (you probably want a polygonal, star shaped domain and conditions that relate the dimension of the domain and the degree of polynomial). Take a look at "The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods" by Brenner and Scott ([link](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387759333)). The answers that you desire probably lie in chapter 4 (probably the section entitled Inverse Estimates, but other things might be useful too). I can't find the exact result right now, but give it a look; if you can't find something useful, I can give it a look later.

Comment: I have Brenner and Scott sat on my desk, it was my first point of call. It turned out to be possible to get even further than this by using the trace theorem to convert the boundary integral into volume integrals given sufficient regularity.